# Visa requirements traveling in Transit via Heathrow

Tags: visas, transit, uk, lhr

Traveling from Boston via London (Heathrow) to South Africa. Will be in Transit. Do I need a visa?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa), it's the official site to make the combinations, there is data only you can provide.